# Write 3 by 4 matrix as a product of elementary matrices and a row echelon form matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I want to write $A$ as a product of $4$ matrices $B$,$C$,$D$, and $E$ such that $B$,$C$, and $D$ are elementary matrices and $E$ is row-echelon form.

$$
A = \begin{bmatrix}
0&1&7&8\\
1&3&3&8\\
-2&5&1&8
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Thanks

Comment: Do you understand the relationship between elementary matrices and row operations? What row operations would you perform on $A$ to get it into row-echelon form?

Comment: Hi, I don't know whether this is an answer or question! Yep I know!

Answer (score 0):

First we swap the first two rows so there is a pivot in the first entry:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&3&8\\0&1&7&8\\-2&5&1&8
\end{bmatrix}.
$$

Next we add $2$ times the first row to the third row to have a zero in the third entry in the first column:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&3&8\\0&1&7&8\\0&11&7&24
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
Finally we add $-11$ times the second row to have a zero in the third entry in the second column:
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
1&3&3&8\\
0&1&7&8\\
0&0&-70&-64
\end{bmatrix}.
$$
The matrix is now in row-echelon form. I will leave it to you to determine the elementary matrices corresponding to the three row operations we performed.

Comment: thank u. My problem is this matrix is 3 by 4. my elementary matrices are 3 b 3. I just need to multiply those three with the last REF matrix? After finding the elementary matrices Would you please let me know what should I do?

Comment: And we should divide third row to -70 to have ref?

Comment: Your question indicated that only 3 elementary row operations should be performed. I do not believe the leading coefficients need be $1$ for a matrix to be considered in "row-echelon form."

Comment: 3 elementary matrix and 1 row echelon form I would be more than happy if you solve it completely. I have reason for it//// Also the definition of row echelon form: the leading entry should be one